# Calling separate Javascript functions in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a separate Javascript function with a parameter being an html variable.

Code:

```
<h4>Enter your name:</h4>

    <!-- the text box -->

    <input type="text"id="name"value="">

    <!-- this is the button to submit the text -->

    <input type="button" value="Submit" 
    onclick="inp = parseFloat( document.getElementById('name').value );

    <!-- This is where I call the function -->      

    qual(inp,4);">
```

This is the part of the "qual" function where it analyzes the text inputted by the user:

```
if(Capp == 4) {
switch(inpt) {
        case "first_text":
            <!-- this is allowing this name to be allowed into the site -->
            allow[4] = 0;
        break
        case "second_text":
            <!-- 0 means true 1 means false -->
            allow[4] = 0;
        break
        default:
            allow[4] = 1;
    }
}
```

the computer is taking in the first parameter as "inp" when I want take in the text that the user types. The output of the html document based on the "allow" array is 00011 or "true, true, true, false, false". I did some digging around and found that the function was taking in "inp" and I am not sure how to get the document to recognize this as a variable.

How would I do this?

- Ian S.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not just call a function onSubmit that reads the value? Seems (from the code) you're placing an awful lot on an html attribute?

Comment: Yeah, is there a special reason not to have a separate javascript file loaded with the HTML that handles all your dynamic-ness? HTML is not meant to do logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wrap the "inp" around the JavaScript function `eval()` so it will be `eval(inp)` but you want to go through these articles to learn about the "evil" of `eval()`

[How evil is eval?](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

[What are the security issues with “eval()” in JavaScript?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

From looking at your code I would say your issue is the `onClick`, you are trying to pass a undeclared variable in an event handler.  You would be better off calling the `qual` function in the `onClick` and grabbing the value you need in the  function itself.

This will call your quality `fun`

Hope that helps.